# Adding huge number in list box as choice in Infopath

Tags: 2013, infopath, form

Are there any easy ways of adding a plurality of digits in listbox in infopath.

I want to add from number 1 to number 150 in infopath list box as a choice.

I should enter the digits manually number by number or there is a easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Create a list in SharePoint, edit it in Datasheet view mode, create the first item with number 1, then drag and drop the little square down (as you would do in Excel).
This will quickly create all the numbers you need.

Then, go to Infopath, add a datasource to retrieve data from the aforementioned list, and bind it to a listbox.

Easy ;)

[image]

Comment: thank this is an alternative plan because i have more than one control and their number of choise different for each other. like one control 150, second control 125, third control 88 and go on.

Comment: by the way data sheet mode does not allow to drag and drop square, it repeats the first column only.

Comment: @MustafaUnlu see the attached screeshot ;)

Comment: i m using sharepoint 2013 and it does not behave like this.

Comment: they managed to ruin this as well then. cool! another +1 for MS